# Detecting Magick use by using the Prime Sphere

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, quintessence, mage-20th-anniversary

I have a *Mage: the Ascension 20th Anniversary Edition* game running and one of the players played a game of *Mage the Ascension Second Edition* before that with a different Storyteller.

In that chronicle they used the prime sphere as a universal detection spell for the use of magick (however that player is unsure if that was just a houserule).

The rulebook of *M20* states inside the description of what you can do with the first dot of the Prime Sphere on page 520 (highlights added by the asker):

> **She may spot energetic ebbs and flows, can sense and at least try to
> read Resonance and Synergy signatures**, and could also  absorb
> Quintessence  into  her  personal  Pattern.

---

One wiki states for a 1 dot rote of the prime sphere:

> **Etheric Senses:** The mage can perceive Quintessential energy, and is
> alerted when someone uses magic in their vicinity. [source](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_(MTAs))

They state *Mage: The Ascension Revised Edition* Pg. 179-180 as the source for this rote together with page 520 in the *M20* core rulebook.

**Is that a correct application of rules as written in *Mage the Ascension Second Edition* and would the rules of *Mage: the Ascension 20th Anniversary Edition* allow for a similar reading?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From just before the part you quoted in M20:

> A beginning study of Prime allows the mage to perceive and channel Quintessence from Nodes, Tass, Wonders, and magickal Effects.

So there's a "perceive magickal Effects" there, but the sentence is more than a little awkward to parse. For more detail, here's an excerpt from the M20 "How do you do that?" book, with irrelevant parts snipped out.

> Sensing Magick
>
> Given their affinity to magick, mages can usually sense it when it’s been used in their vicinity. ... Depending on the mages and the magick involved, those impressions might possess a distinct smell, leave a tingling sensation in the air, or perhaps even smear the area with a greasy metaphysical residue.
>
> In game terms, a Perception + Awareness roll can help a mage spot magickal energies within roughly 100 feet of her. Generally, the difficulty is 6...
>
> A Prime 1 Effect can help that mage sense the residue of magick that has been used within the area. The “afterglow” of small spells fades quickly – within five minutes or so. ...

So the official answer seems to be "You don't need even need Prime 1 to sense magic, but if you've got it you can even sense *recent* magic and not just ongoing effects.